# Dialog Box Android

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have dialog box for login and there is a option for signup and I want when clicking on signup option, layout gets changed in same dialog box.
Here is my code:-

```
myDialog =  new Dialog(this);
   // myDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogSlideAnim;
    ((ViewGroup)myDialog.getWindow().getDecorView())
    .getChildAt(0).startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
    MainScreenActivity.this,android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDialog.setCancelable(true);
    Button login = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
 emailaddr = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.login_username);
 password = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.login_password);
 TextView tv = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.login_singup);
 myDialog.getWindow().setLayout(1050, 900);
 myDialog.show();

login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom, R.anim.abc_slide_out_top);

   }


  });
    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


        }
    });
```

Comment: yup by setting animation for that too like in previous one.

Comment: @BobMalooga i  have  updated the question